# How to get sound energy in javascript web audio api?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'd like to want to create a JS library to detect song BPM.
I've read this  [article](http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/beatdetection/) and understood the algorithm.
Is it right way to get 10 seconds sound energy data? I'm a novice. If you don't understand some parts of the code, please ask

```js
var audioFileInput = document.querySelector('#audio-file-input');
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();

// call countBpm function on "change" event in audioFileInput
audioFileInput.onchange = function() {
  var file = this.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    countBpm(reader.result)
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
};

function countBpm(buffer) {
  audioCtx.decodeAudioData(buffer, function(decodedData) {
    var dataFromLeftChannel = getSoundDataFromMiddle(decodedData, 'left');
    var dataFromRightChannel = getSoundDataFromMiddle(decodedData, 'right');
    console.dir(dataFromLeftChannel);
    console.dir(dataFromRightChannel);
    // code to detect bpm will be here
  })
};

// get 10 seconds sound energy data from channels
function getSoundDataFromMiddle(decodedData, channel) {
  var positions = {};
  positions.start = (decodedData.length / 2) - 220500;
  positions.end = (decodedData.length / 2) + 220500;

  if (channel === 'left') {
    return decodedData.getChannelData(0).subarray(positions.start, positions.end);
  } else if (channel === 'right') {
    return decodedData.getChannelData(1).subarray(positions.start, positions.end);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="audio-file-input" type="file" accept="audio/*"></input>
```

Comment: I suppose you mean in-browser javascript. Start by reading about the Web Audio Api, AudioContext, etc. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Comment: Even if the question is interesting... that's basically a *"please write some code for me"* question. How can you expect to understand any of the code specially if involved technologies are quite new? Also your question relies purely on an external article that might go down one day, making your question quite useless... Can you improve it and show *anything* (code)?

Comment: @Eloims, i added my code to the post.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, i added my code to the post. Please check it.

Comment: The bpm tag is for business process management. Not beats per minute.